# Issue using Jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am having trouble getting the built-in jquery tabs working on my site.  I'm not really sure what the issue is.  I have basically taken the code directly from the demo page that comes with jquery and copied it to my own site (obviously making the paths correct), however, it refuses to work and I really can't see where the issue is.  I'm failing to see why it is not working.  If anyone could take a quick look at my code and see if they see anything obvious I would greatly appreciate it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="development-bundle/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="development-bundle/ui/ui.tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="development-bundle/ui/ui.core.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="development-bundle/demos/demos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="development-bundle/themes/base/ui.all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">

                <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
                <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you are loading ui.core.js after ui.tabs.js;

Since ui.tabs depends on things in ui.core, this might be the cause of your problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox+Firebug to debug your javascript. Enable the console and Javascript debugging and see if you have any Javascript errors.

Also, download something like [Charles HTTP Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and verify your included Javascript files are indeed loading and are not 404.

Btw, correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you're using jQueryUI, not just vanilla jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a heck of a time getting tabs to work. Show us the whole file. Looks like you've cut off the bottom because I don't see that all your `<div>` tags are closed with `</div>` tags. Is your page validating?

Also, can you fix your indentation so that your HTML is easier to understand? Your `</ul>` doesn't match with its corresponding `<ul>`.